# Как запустить pylint через командную строку, если проверяемый скрипт и pylint расположены в разных папках?

Tags: python, командная-строка

Всем привет! Хочу использовать pylint для анализа скрипта. Создал скрипт в папке: **C:\Users\user\Desktop\Desktop2\tut_pylint**

Для установки pylint ввожу через консоль `pip install pylint`. Запускаю команду из директории **C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Scripts**, иначе получаю ошибку

```
"pip" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Для анализа моего скрипта иду обратно в папку со скриптом, ввожу команду `pylint simple1.py`, появляется эта же ошибка, указанная выше.

Каким образом применить pylint для этого скрипта? Спасибо!

P.S.:
В переменной Path уже добавил путь к директории с `pip`:

```
C:\Users\user; C:\Users\user\anaconda3;
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Scripts
```

Comment: Просто указывать полные пути, например

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При вызове команды pylint по совету товарища из комментариев прописал полный путь
`pylint "C:\\Users\user\Desktop\Desktop2\tut_pylint\simple1.py"`, находясь при этом в директории, содержащей pip. Команда запустилась без проблем.